# Is every positive-density set of positive integers almost rational?

Tags: additive-combinatorics

(All the sets in this discussion are sets of positive integers.) I say a set $V$ is “rational” if it satisfies one of the following conditions:

I. $V$ is finite (possibly empty);

II. $V$ can be written as the union of a finite (possibly empty) set and finitely many arithmetic progressions of infinite length.

Letting $\Delta$ denote the symmetric difference operation, I say that a set $W$ is “almost rational” if there exists a rational set $V$ such that $V\Delta W$ has zero natural density. Clearly, every $W$ of density $0$ or $1$ is almost rational (with $V$ being any finite set in the former case, and $V$ being any set whose complement is finite, in the latter case). My question is: are there any sets of positive natural density which are *not* almost rational?

Comment: How about the complement of powers of two? Or diagonalize against an enumeration of arithmetic progressions with the next element removed at least twice as large as the previous removed element. Gerhard "Can Think Of Thinner Sets" Paseman, 2019.10.08.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Complement of powers of two has density $1$.

Comment: @Wojowu, of course I realized that after commenting, not before. What if we make the removed set thicker? Gerhard "Now Thinking Of Thicker Sets" Paseman, 2019.10.08.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I imagine this strategy should work, but the details might be a little cumbersome

Comment: OK then. How about Thue Morse? The set of all positive numbers with an even number of bits in their binary expansion? Gerhard "Is Grabbing At Bits Now" Paseman, 2019.10.08.

Comment: $\{n:\sqrt{2}n$ mod $2\;\in [0,1]\}$

Comment: @YCor: do you have a proof that your set is not almost-rational?

Comment: Any set with irrational natural density works.

Comment: Indeed, write (mod $\pi$) instead of (mod 2) in my previous comment and this yields irrational density.

Comment: Interesting. That makes sense. But, I wonder: if the density is rational, is the set then necessarily almost rational?

Comment: @MCS no, even with rational density it's not "almost rational". Indeed if it has density $t$ then it will meet every arithmetic progression $D$ with density $$t$ inside $D$. In particular, it will not contain, up to density zero, an arithmetic progression at all.